# How to complete remote mysqldump using pem file?

Tags: mysql

I've mysql server setup in remote server. I can access it using pem file through workbench using connection method as ssh over IP. I want to take backup of one of the DBs from my remote server.

I know, I can use following command to do remote mysqldump,

```
mysqldump -P3306  -h192.168.1.101 -uroot -ppassword database > /root/user/my.sql
```

But, I don't have password for the mysql server. I use .pem file for authenticating. So, how do I run mysqldump command?

**Edit 1**:
I tried following command

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my.pem -f -L3310:localhost:3306 ubuntu@<server-ip> -N
```

But couldn't succeed. It throws following error,

> REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!

So, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654064/ubuntu-ssh-warning-remote-host-identification-has-changed). But same error. :(

Comment: You need to make an ssh tunnel http://stackoverflow.com/q/2989724/448579

Comment: @ParrisVarney How do I create ssh tunnel using pem file?

Comment: Add `-i /path/to/pem` to the ssh side of the command

Comment: I get error of `REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!`. But I'm using same key in mysql workbench to connect to it :|. Added the command which I tried in my question.

Comment: I'm at a loss, if the key works with workbench, then it should work for ssh.  Is workbench using the ubuntu user?

Comment: Yes. It has ubuntu user and root as mysql user

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you eventually solved this, but I did by using the following:

```
mysqldump --ssl-key=/path/to/pem -u your_username -p -h your.host.com  your_db > your_dump.sql
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

## mysqldump from remote server use SSL

### 1- Security with SSL

192.168.0.101 - remote server

192.168.0.102 - local server

**Remore server**

```
CREATE USER 'backup_remote_2'@'192.168.0.102' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY '3333333' REQUIRE SSL;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'backup_remote_2'@'192.168.0.102';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

-

**Local server**

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump \
 --databases test_1 \
 --host=192.168.0.101 \
 --user=backup_remote_2 \
 --password=3333333 \
 --master-data \
 --set-gtid-purged \
 --events \
 --triggers \
 --routines \
 --verbose \
 --ssl-mode=REQUIRED \
 --result-file=/home/db_1.sql
```

====================================

### 2 - Security with SSL (REQUIRE X509)

192.168.0.101 - remote server

192.168.0.102 - local server

**Remore server**

```
CREATE USER 'backup_remote'@'192.168.0.102' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY '1111111' REQUIRE X509;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'backup_remote'@'192.168.0.102';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

-

**Local server**

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump \
 --databases test_1 \
 --host=192.168.0.101 \
 --user=backup_remote \
 --password=1111111 \
 --events \
 --triggers \
 --routines \
 --verbose \
 --ssl-mode=VERIFY_CA \
 --ssl-ca=/usr/local/mysql/data/ssl/ca.pem \
 --ssl-cert=/usr/local/mysql/data/ssl/client-cert.pem \
 --ssl-key=/usr/local/mysql/data/ssl/client-key.pem \
 --result-file=/home/db_name.sql
```

---

### [Note]

**On local server**

/usr/local/mysql/data/ssl/

```
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1.7K Apr 16 22:28 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1.1K Apr 16 22:28 ca.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1.1K Apr 16 22:28 client-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1.7K Apr 16 22:28 client-key.pem
```

Copy this files from remote server for (REQUIRE X509) or if SSL without (REQUIRE X509) do not copy

---

**On remote server**

/usr/local/mysql/data/

```
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1.7K Apr 16 22:28  ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1.1K Apr 16 22:28  ca.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1.1K Apr 16 22:28  client-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1.7K Apr 16 22:28  client-key.pem
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1.7K Apr 16 22:28  private_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql  451 Apr 16 22:28  public_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1.1K Apr 16 22:28  server-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1.7K Apr 16 22:28  server-key.pem
```

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
# SSL
ssl_ca=/usr/local/mysql/data/ca.pem
ssl_cert=/usr/local/mysql/data/server-cert.pem
ssl_key=/usr/local/mysql/data/server-key.pem
```

Increase Password Security

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html